# Optimizely get media item from internal URL

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I have a **URL property type** on an Optimizely block that could be an external URL or media item.
When rendered, the the URL is of the format: `/link/some_kind_of_id.aspx`

That relative URL will work, as the Epi HTTP handler will determine if it's a media item or not, and return whatever the resource is.

What I need to do is programmatically use this ID to determine if the URL is that of an uploaded media item so I can get the filename of the uploaded media item and do some additional processing.

However, I can't find any information in any old or new Epi/Opti documentation/guides.

I was hoping I could use something like the ContentLoader to get the content or the BlobFactory. The former requires a content link and the latter requires a GUID - I have neither.

Is there any way I can programmatically get more info from a URL property value via it's "UriInternal" link?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IUrlResolver.Route(...)` has an overload that takes an `UrlBuilder` where you can pass in this value. If it return an `IContent` object, then you know it's a content item. You can then check if it's an `IContentMedia`.